# конверт картинки png to jpeg

Tags: php

здравствуйте, у меня есть функция сохранения изображения

```
    public function upload_img() {
     if($this->ifimage()) {
        $path = $this->create_idir().str_shuffle(md5($_FILES['img']['name'])).'.jpg';
                if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES["img"]["tmp_name"], $this->cdndir. $path))  {
                        return $path;
                    }
        }
    return false;
```

}

и у меня вопрос, если поступают png картинки, как правильнее всего в данном случае конвертировать их в jpeg?

Comment: А если png как png сохранять? Или только jpg подходят?

Comment: надо конвертить в jpg

Comment: а в каком месте идет проверка на расширения? Преобразовать не проблема, но надо сперва отличить файл по расширению.

Answer (score 1):

Функция для безопасного преобразования png в jpg, вместо прозрачности будет белый фон:

```
$image = imagecreatefrompng($filePath);
$bg = imagecreatetruecolor(imagesx($image), imagesy($image));
imagefill($bg, 0, 0, imagecolorallocate($bg, 255, 255, 255));
imagealphablending($bg, TRUE);
imagecopy($bg, $image, 0, 0, 0, 0, imagesx($image), imagesy($image));
imagedestroy($image);
$quality = 50; // 0 = worst / smaller file, 100 = better / bigger file 
imagejpeg($bg, $filePath . ".jpg", $quality);
imagedestroy($bg);
```

Качество JPG задается в переменной $quality,  от 0 до 100, чем больше, тем лучше качество и размер файла.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1201798/use-php-to-convert-png-to-jpg-with-compression